# Laravel Passport: Unable to access user data and redirected to login page

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am successfully getting an access and refresh token, but my problem is when I try to return the user. I have this code inside my `routes/api.php` file

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', function() {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `$request->user()` but you are not passing any `Request` to function.

Change this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', function() {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

to

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', function(Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am still redirected to the login page

Comment: do you have a valid token ?

Comment: are you sending token like this: Authorization: Bearer  your token......

Comment: well i am successfully creating a token with post request to 'https://nima.izdavam.com/laravelcpanel/oauth/token' and i am getting the "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 31536000,
 "access_token": ....
        "refresh_token": ....

Comment: you mean this one Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 11:13:15 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.0
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=cdscdsc; expires=Wed, 17-Oct-2018 13:13:15 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: givetake_session=cdscds; expires=Wed, 17-Oct-2018 13:13:15 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182021/discussion-between-dimitar-and-salman-zafar).